# Can't change Trello card due date to 12:00 AM

Tags: trello

I have an existing card in Trello that I mistakenly set to a due date of 10/27 12:00PM.  It should be 10/27 12:00 AM.  So I click on the card, then click on the due date and type AM over PM.  I then click Save, but the change doesn't take.  I can change it to a different time, like 1:00 AM, but it won't seem to let me change it to 12:00 AM.

Is this a bug?  Does anyone else see this problem or just me?

Comment: After more testing, it looks like a due date can't be changed to between 12:00AM and 12:59AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the time to be `00:00` or `00:00 AM`

For some reason it won't recognize `12AM` as a time, but `00` will do it for you. This is a possible bug that you can report, but a pretty simple workaround.

Comment: Where do I report this as a bug?

Comment: You can try emailing `support@trello.com`. There is also an alias for feature requests: `feature-ideas@trello.com` however I think this qualifies as more of a bug.